# How to send TTL output from Arduino Uno to Raspberry Pi?

Tags: arduino, communication

I am trying to send TTL pulse at 1second interval to Raspberry pi? Can someone suggest me a good way to do it using GPIO or any other way possible.

**Arduino Code:**

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
    delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
}
```

**Raspberry Pi Code:**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
pinTTL = 4

GPIO.setup(pinTTL, GPIO.IN)

start_time = time.time()
t_end = start_time + 60
while time.time()<t_end:
    inputState = GPIO.input(pinTTL)
    if inputState == True:
        print 'HIGH', time.time() - start_time
    else:
        print 'LOW', time.time() - start_time

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Another thing is I have checked using multimeter, the voltage on Pi output pin does change at 1second interval.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where is your Arduino code?  Where is your Pi code?  How have you dropped the Arduino 5V GPIO to a Pi safe 3V3?

Comment: I have dropped the 5v arduino output to 3.3v for making it safe for Pi. I just used a normal arduino code for setting the pin output high and low at 1second interval to see if this works and whether the raspberry pi input pin detects that but I coulnd't get it work

Comment: Edit your question and include the Arduino and Pi code you are using.

Comment: added the scripts

Comment: Presumably you haven't connected the correct Arduino pin to the correct Pi pin.  Please add a photo.  http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html#Type_3 shows the position of GPIO4 on pin 7.

Comment: I had connected to pin 7 correctly but the problem resolved after moving the input to pin31 (GPIO 6) on its own. Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem lied somewhere in connection only. Changing the **pinTTL=6** solved the problem.